# Nav Menu Jerky with hover

Tags: css, html, nav

How could I stop the [jerkiness](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhM3T/) in my hover it seems to move a few pixels:

**CSS:**

```
header nav ul li{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
header nav li a {
    color:#8f3479;
    text-align:center;
    width:30px;
    padding:15px;
}
header nav li a:hover, .current{
    padding:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#8f3479;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<header>
        <div class="branding"></div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="current" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            <nav>   
  </header>
```

Comment: The "jerkiness" is because your font becomes bold on hover, and a bold font is wider. Are you looking for a way to keep the bold on hover, but eliminate the "jerkiness"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because of the bold treatment on the hover state. If you add bold to the regular links as well, it will remain the same for both states. 
see this fiddle for example - http://jsfiddle.net/ZhM3T/1/